# Is there a way to easily check if a string is filled with either spaces / tabs / EOL and nothing else?

Tags: c, string

I am creating a program where I read lines 1 by 1 from a file. I wanted to implement a check where after the line is read and stored in a string it is checked to see if any one of its characters are not a space/tab/EOL. So essentially what I am trying to do is skip over the line and not store it if the entire line doesn't have any content other then spaces/tabs/EOL's.

Comment: Loop throught the characters of the string and test for each character if it's different from the ones mentioned in your question....show what you have tried.

Comment: Actually, whenever you want to check whether a line contains any character that is not considered space, you'll have to iterate over the entire string in the worst case.

Comment: @tchelidze it's a C and not C++. BTW your test doesn't account for tabs.

Comment: You could try `strcspn` which returns the index of the first char in the set provided.

Comment: Yes there is a way. But there is no `EOL` character code in ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use strpbrk to search characters in a string.  Returns a pointer to the position of the first occurrence or NULL if none found.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strpbrk.htm

Comment: Hmm I didn't even know that function existed. However, the OP wants to check if there are any characters **other than** whitespace. This would be useful if the OP wanted to check for whitespace, but unless the OP passes this function a list of **every** non-whitespace character, this function will not work as the OP has requested.

Comment: You are doing a negative check.  If the unwanted characters are found, you reject.

Comment: if( !strpbrk( buffer, " \t\n" ) ) store( buffer );

Comment: *... it is checked to see if any one of its characters are not a space/tab/EOL.* Based on what the OP has said, I believe he wants to check to make sure a string contains at least one non-whitespace character. Based on that, I believe he's saying a string like `Hello, World!` would be completely acceptable despite the fact that this string contains a space. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the OP, though.

Comment: Oh I now see what you are doing. Thanks for posting that second comment with an example. My mistake.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis would this be acceptable since I am not looking for EOF either.                           if( !strpbrk( buffer, " \t\n**EOF**" ) ) store( buffer ); Would EOF being included like that in the strpbrk function also be considered one of the characters to look out for?

Comment: @Brandon EOF is not a character you would read into a buffer from an input file.  You have to check that upon reading from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your string `buffer` and let's go through it one character at a time.

```
char *tmp = buffer; // give tmp the address of the buffer's first character.

// Assuming you have bool defined.
// If you don't, just switch this with whatever you prefer to use for bools.
bool bHasValidChar = false;

while(*tmp){
    if(*tmp != ' ' && *tmp != '\t' && *tmp != '\n'){
        // Cool, this character is not whitespace
        bHasValidChar = true;
        break;
    }else{
        // The character is whitespace
        // Move on and test the next character
        tmp++;
    }
}

if(bHasValidChar){
    // Contains non-whitespace. Do something.
}else{
    // Str is only whitespace. Do something.
}
```

If you don't have bool (*you may not have it if you're using an old version of C*), then use an int instead of bool (with 1 & 0 in place of true and false), or whatever you prefer.

Hope this helps.

**Note**: *This was typed off of my phone, so it has not been tested. I apologize for any errors in my post & code, but hopefully this will get you started down the right direction.*

Comment: Why not just use `isspace()`? But actually SO is no coding service. You did OP not a favour by providing full code.

Comment: While the code may need fixing, I didn't check, the idea is the best.

Comment: @Olaf, it's been a long time since I have coded in C, so I completely forgot that function existed xD Thanks for the suggestion. Using `isspace()` would definitely be cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

3 ways: see if any non-white-space exist

```
char nws[2];
if (sscanf(buf, "%1s", nws) == 1) foo(buf);
else skip();  // all white-space

// or if code wants to use specific ws characters
if (buf[strspn(buf, " \t\r\n")] != '\0') skip();

int Interesting(const char *s) {
  // Take advantage that the null character is not a white-space
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *s)) {
    s++;
  }
  return *s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to loop over the string until the end or until you find a character that is *not* one of the "allowed characters":

```
char only_whitespace(char const * str /* NULL terminated */) {
  for (; *str; ++str) {
    switch (*str) {
      case 32: /* space */
      case  9: /* TAB */
      case 10: /* line feed */
      case 13: /* carriage return, windows... */
        break;
      default: return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

If you want to be the cause of some *WTF*s in the future (by the one maintaining your code, this could also be your future self), add this for extra speed:

```
char only_whitespace(char const * str /* NULL terminated */) {
  for (; *str; ++str) {
    if ((*str >> 6) || (*str & 16)) {
      return 0;
    }
    switch (*str) {
      case 32: /* space */
      case  9: /* TAB */
      case 10: /* line feed */
      case 13: /* carriage return, windows... */
        break;
      default: return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Reason:

```
0b00100000 = 32
0b00001001 =  9
0b00001010 = 10
0b00001101 = 13

0b00010000 = 16
```

---

**Wait a second...**

> I am creating a program where I read lines 1 by 1 from a file.  [..]

If you're reading line by line, then there won't be any "end of line" character(s) in your line. That's the point of reading line by line. So you only need to check for space or tab characters.

---

With this, we can also go crazy:

```
0b00100000 = 32 (space)
0b00001001 = 9 (tab)
---------- bitwise or
0b00101001
---------- bitwise not
0b11010110 = 0xD6 (mask of bits that must not be set)
```

Now, assuming a 64-bit architecture, we can replicate that bit mask 8 times and use it to do a quick "pre scan" of the string, speeding up the check if we expect a high rate of strings that do not only consist of whitespace characters. Though we should know the length before, otherwise obtaining the length will probably ruin any performance gains:

```
char only_whitespace_with_prescan64(char const * const str /* one line */, size_t length) {
  uint64_t const * cursor = (uint64_t const *) str;
  uint32_t mask32 = 0xD6 | (0xD6 << 8) | (0xD6 << 16) | (0xD6 << 24);
  uint64_t mask64 = ((uint64_t) mask32) << 32 | mask32;
  for (; length != 0; --length, ++cursor) {
    if (*cursor & mask64) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return only_whitespace(str);
}
```

Though whether this really brings any (noticeable) performance gain depends both on the frequency of its use and of course on the type of data you expect. Using stuff like that should only be done when you noticed while profiling your program that the function is actually a performance bottleneck.

*NOTE: All of the above code is entirely untested.*

Comment: Certainly using `case '\t'` instead of `case 9`, etc. is easier to understand.  Consider `' '` instead of 32, etc.

Comment: @chux Probably. Normally I'd use character literals for stuff like that, but chose against them here to empathize the dependence on ASCII and for the "optimization" (:D). With the comments this piece of code should be clear enough, though.